# Saved svg (generated by Matplotlib) does not show gridlines in visio

Tags: python, svg, grid, visio

I have ploted a simple picture. But when the format of the saved figure is svg, then I open it in visio, and the grid line would not be shown as it shows in Python. The other saved formats, PDF, png, jpf have the normal grid lines, which is same as they show in Python.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

x = np.arange(10)
y = x**2 plt.plot(x, y)
plt.grid('on')
plt.savefig("pic.svg")
# plt.savefig("pic.pdf")
plt.show()
```

[image: The saved .pdf show the grid lines]
[image: The saved .svg does not show the grid lines]

As suggested by [HS-nebula](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10852841/hs-nebula), the saved svg has the gridlines in Word. But I want to edit it. Why the gridlines don't apper in visio?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Just to clarify, you say you're using Seaborn to make the plot but your code doesn't use Seaborn at all. Is that the case?

Comment: Also, when I run your code and load the SVG file into Word, the gridlines appear. Perhaps the issue is with Visio?

Comment: Thank  you for your reply. Yeah, it is a simple example to show that svg doesn't have gridlines in visio. In fact, I use Seaborn.

Comment: When I load the svg into word as you suggested, the gridlines appear. But I want to edit it :(

Comment: Why can't you edit it in Python?

Comment: Same problem. DId you solve it?